# VB Script - Remove special characters from the csv file

Tags: replace, vbscript, special-characters

In my input csv file , I might have the below special characters in anywhere of the file. I have to replace the below special characters with some alternate text. How can I do this in vb script?

> ® ³ ·• ½ × ï Ε  – ∞∞ ‘“ ≤≥ •

Comment: Read and follow  _Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog_: [How Can I Find and Replace Text in a Text File?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/02/08/how-can-i-find-and-replace-text-in-a-text-file/). Then, [edit] your question and show a [mcve] of your code if you get stuck at something.

Comment: What's the character encoding used to write your csv file? (All text has an encoding. If you don't know what it is then you can't read it correctly.) VB Script works naturally with UTF-16 but can convert using the default ANSI codepage. The default ANSI codepage is one of dozens of encodings and varies over time, user and system, so it makes communication very complicated. Note: Confusingly, UTF-16 is called Unicode in VB Script documentation and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate each cell of the CSV file and in each cell verify each byte and compare it with the Ascii values based on your requirement and if the Ascii value of that doesn't fall under the range of values we are expecting we can replace it with whatever text you require. Sample code below

```
Workbooks.Open("Your CSV file")
for k = 1 to Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).usedrange.rows.count

for j= 1 to Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).usedrange.columns.count
value=Activeworkbook.sheets(1).cells(k,j)
newvalue=""
for i=1 to len(value)-1

temp=mid(value,i,1)
if (Asc(temp)<127 and Asc(temp)>31 )then ' i am just assuming only the values on keyboard should be included any other conditions required for your requirement can be implied here

newvalue=newvalue & temp

else

newvalue=newvalue &"required text"
endif

next

activeworkbook.sheets(1).cells(k,j)=newvalue

next
next
```

Comment: That would be VBA, not VB Script. Though, working in Excel could be much more productive. Perhaps the question asker would shift the work there.